# Windows 10 explorer, auto expand to current folder is not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In Windows 10 explorer, auto expand to current folder is not working in spite of having the following settings: Navigation pane expand to open folder is checked; and in registry the key is set to 1 as shown in the following screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: windows 10 pro version 1909